# Capacitor app version check and updater dialog using app update

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am working ionic with capacitor. I want to make app update and want to force app user to use latest version. By using cordova it's very easy as bellow:

[App update with cordova](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/app-update/)

I want to do the same by using capacitor and tried different ways. Also did not get proper documantation for app update with Capacitor. Could you please help me?

Comment: Did you pass the version code to your backend in your api call ? in your request headers or in post params ?

Comment: I have changed version in "android/app/build.gradle" at "versionName". Wanted to use import { AppUpdate } from '@ionic-native/app-update/ngx'; But it's giving error to build apk